# Calculate sample size to mcnemar test

Tags: r, sample-size

I want to calculate sample size by using the mcnemar test to compare 2 values ​​of sensitivity. I am looking for the formula to implement under r for this calculation.
In this case i need to calculate the sample size with Sensitivity_1 = 0.78, Sensitivity_2 = 0.558, with discordant pairs = 0.4664
(Sensitivity_2 * (1 - Sensitivity_1 ) + Sensitivity_1 * (1 - Sensitivity_2 ))
to have 0.232 (Sensitivity_1 -Sensitivity_2) of difference.

Comment: Have you tried `mcnemar.test`, which is available in every R installation? It's the first hit if you Google "R McNemar Test".

Comment: ii think the mcnemar.test is used to do comparison.  In my case i need to calculate the sample size with p1 = 0.78, p2= 0.558, with discordant pairs = 0.4664 to have 0.232 of difference.

Comment: it's helpful if you include this information in your question - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the`biostatUZH` package help?

For Windows:

```
install.packages("biostatUZH", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

For Mac:

```
install.packages("biostatUZH", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type = "source")
```

See `sampleSizeMcNemar()` to compute sample size for McNemar test.

```
#example from Lachenbruch (1982), Table II, first row
sampleSizeMcNemar(p1 = 0.8, p2 = 0.9, alpha = 0.05, power = 0.9)
```